# Jquery loop with html

Tags: jquery, loops

I need to loop the content about this in the `<div class="newsList">`:

```
                   <figure class="effect-lily">
                        <img src="img/1.jpg" alt="img06">
                        <figcaption>
                            <div>
                                <h2><span>Lily</span></h2>
                                <p>Lily likes to play with crayons and pencils</p>
                            </div>
                            <a href="https://tympanus.net/Development/HoverEffectIdeas/index.html#">View more</a>
                        </figcaption>           
                    </figure>
```

my jquery is:

```
            $(function() {
                $.ajax({
                  url: "test.json",
                  dataType:'json',
                  type: 'GET',
                  data:'data',
                  success: function getData(data){ 
                    console.log(data);

                    var str = '';
                    var hasData = 0;
                    var newsList = $('.newsList');

                    for(var i=0; i<data.length;i++){
                        var ntitle = JSON.stringify(data[i].title);
                        var desc = JSON.stringify(data[i].description);
                        var writer = JSON.stringify(data[i].writer);
                        var str = '';
                        console.log(data[i].title);
                        console.log(data[i].description);
                        if(data.length>0) {
                            str += '<figure class="effect-lily"><img src="img/1.jpg" alt="img06"><figcaption><div><h2><span>'+ntitle+'</span></h2><p>'+desc+'</p></div><a href="https://tympanus.net/Development/HoverEffectIdeas/index.html#">View more</a></figcaption></figure>';
                        }


                    }
                    newsList.html(str);

                },
                  error: function(result){ 
                    console.log('error');
                  }
                })
            });
```

but now I cannot loop my content in the  `<div class="newsList">`, it's just show only one item in spite of the JSON has seven item.
what's wrong with me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are re-initialising the variable `str` within the loop. Declare `var str = '';` outside of the for loop.

ie. Move `var str = '';` to one line above the for loop

Comment: Just deleting that line would do it, given `str` is already declared before the loop. Also, the `if` inside the loop is redundant, the condition will always be true. (Which of course doesn't actually break the function, but it could be tidied up.)